# ACLs with robocopy

Tags: windows, robocopy

I am trying to copy data from a Windows Server 2012 R2 to a QNAP NAS(ext4).
I use the `/MIR` switch and I want to keep the ACLs on files and sub-folders unchanged.

The problem is that the ACLs in the source folder and target folder are different. I tried something like that:

```
robocopy <source> <target> /MIR /copy:DATS  /R:5 /MT:24 /W:1 /NP /ZB /M /V /XD *$RECYCLE.BIN*
```

also I have long path names it's over 290 C .

Comment: What OS and filesystem is the NAS, as it sounds like the NAS filesystem/share doesn't support NTFS ACLs (the `S` in `/Copy:DATS`).

Comment: it is a "QNAP NAS "

Comment: Please add that to your question, not as a comment. Please also post what filesystem the share is

Comment: Done................

Comment: FileSystem?  Please address _**all**_ of what was requested.

Comment: The ext4 file-system and Linux have a totally different permission system. Even with advanced ACLs an 100% mapping between Windows ACLs to Linux is often not possible. Therefore what you expect is not achievable. If you want to copy all ACLs you need a domain and a Windows server.

Comment: you are right but a friend advised me to try a program called fastcopy ! should I try or it will not work ?

Comment: Dear Robert : trying a copy program will help to save time or it will wast my time ?

Comment: Hi, Report again, I was asking you a question but no response from you but thanks to and I am backing to share my experience about how my problem solved, I was going to use Fastcopy but a helpful friend like you recommend me a program called gs richcopy 360 , the ACLs in the source folder and target are the same, no long path names problems too .

Comment: Hi, Report again, I was asking you a question but no response from you but thanks to you and I am backing to share my experience about how my problem solved, I was going to use Fastcopy but a helpful friend like you recommend me a program called gs richcopy 360 , the ACLs in the source folder and target are the same, no long path names problems too.